# mrjob limit filesize for output files

Tags: python, mapreduce, emr, mrjob

Does anyone know how to limit the max size of s3 output files (part-r-00000, part-r-00001 ... etc) from mrjob?

I'm compressing the output if that makes any difference using the following in my .mrjob.conf file:

```
jobconf:
 mapred.output.compress: 'true'
 mapred.output.compression.codec: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
```

Thanks in advance,
Conor

Comment: Does this answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610116/how-to-limit-size-of-hadoop-sequence-file

Comment: Yes- thank you very much. :)